# Can someone explain these lines: X1, y1 = np.c_[np.random.normal(loc=new_center[0],

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to create a dataset first thought Gaussian disrtibution (make_blobs) which gives me: 300 rows with 2 columns each X,y then having the maximum of X as a new center next I'm kinda lost I don't know what these lines meant by
so I need these lines to be explained:

```
X1, y1 = np.c_[np.random.normal(loc=new_center[0], size=size),
           np.random.normal(loc=new_center[1], size=size)], np.ones(size)X, y = np.r_[X, X1], np.r_[y, y1].astype(int)
```

then:

```
def plot_dataset_with_class(x, y):
uniques = np.unique(y)
[plt.plot(x[:, 0][y == unique], x[:, 1][y == unique], '.') for unique in uniques]
```

can someone please explain I'm lost !!

the complete code is this:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

"""Create Dataset."""
X, y = make_blobs(300, centers=2, cluster_std=2.3, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
new_center = max(X, key=lambda x: x[1])
size = 100
X1, y1 = np.c_[np.random.normal(loc=new_center[0], size=size),
               np.random.normal(loc=new_center[1], size=size)], np.ones(size)
X, y = np.r_[X, X1], np.r_[y, y1].astype(int)


## Plot dataset method
def plot_dataset(x):
    plt.plot(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], '.')


def plot_dataset_with_class(x, y):
    uniques = np.unique(y)
    [plt.plot(x[:, 0][y == unique], x[:, 1][y == unique], '.') for unique in uniques]

plt.figure()
plot_dataset(X)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both assignments are using tuple shorthand.  They can be broken down further with little extra work thusly:

```
X1 = np.c_[np.random.normal(loc=new_center[0], size=size),
           np.random.normal(loc=new_center[1], size=size)]
y1 = np.ones(size)
X = np.r_[X, X1]
y = np.r_[y, y1].astype(int)
```

The assignment to `X1` is the column stacking of the elements in that list (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#numpy.c_).

The assignment to `y1` is an array of ones of length `size`.

The assignment to `X` is the already existing variable `X` concatenated with `X1` (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_).

The assignment to `y` is the concatenation of existing variable `y` with `y1`, but casted element-wise as integers.

The next bit you ask about: `[plt.plot(x[:, 0][y == unique], x[:, 1][y == unique], '.') for unique in uniques]` plots each class as a different color.  It achieves this by using list comprehension to select points for each class separately (iterating over values of `y` and selecting only the current value of the iterator in each call to plot()), since by default plots are overlayed with different color lines on repeated calls to plot().

Comment: can you explain more please why we need to concatenate them ? I need to uderstand the relation of doing so